# Why this jquery plugin giving error in IE but working fine in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, cross-browser

This page work in Firefox but not in IE7

http://www.robwalshonline.com/demos/randomImageDemo/randomImage_plugin.html

This is page of plugin http://www.robwalshonline.com/posts/jquery-plugin-random-image-on-page-load/

How to get this work in all browser FF, safari, chrome and IE 6, 7 ,8

Comment: I dunno, but I'd have done it in a server-side language.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a comma after the last element of a list or object literal works in FF but is invalid in IE:

```
myImages: ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg', ] //put image names in this bracket. ex: 'harold.jpg', 'maude.jpg', 'etc'
```

Consequently winnerImage will be undefined in IE, and it will try to load the image at http://www.robwalshonline.com/demos/randomImageDemo/images/undefined

Comment: Remove the comma after the last element (before the ]).

Comment: There is still a comma after 'tooman.jpg' in http://www.robwalshonline.com/demos/randomImageDemo/js/jquery.robwalsh.randomImageOnload-1.js